# В одномерном массиве найти числа,сумма которых будет равна 7

Tags: java

Моё задание :

Дан массив целых чисел.
Массив не отсортирован, числа могут повторяться.
Необходимо найти в данном массиве такие два числа n и m ,
что бы их сумма была равна 7.
Например: 2+5=7,6+1=7,-2+9 = 7 ( хотя бы одну пару)
,массив задать вручную. 
Гугл результатов не дал(

```
       int[] q = {10, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    System.out.println(" ---- Начальный вид массива ---- ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q));
    Arrays.sort(q);
    System.out.println("Сортируем с помощью Arrays.sort() ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q));
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Такие задачи решаются использованием мозга, а не гугла. Ответ: 3 и 4 или 1 и 6.

Comment: Что толку в простой сортировке? Сортировать имеет смысл по остатку от деления на 7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так решается:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] q = { 10, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int n = 7;
    System.out.println(" ---- Исследуемый массив ---- ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q));
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < q.length; j++) {
            if (q[i] + q[j] == n) {
                System.out.println("*****************");
                System.out.println("q[" + i + "] = " + q[i]);
                System.out.println("q[" + j + "] = " + q[j]);
                System.out.println("q[" + i + "] + q[" + j + "] = " + n);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
 ---- Исследуемый массив ---- 
[10, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
*****************
q[2] = 1
q[5] = 6
q[2] + q[5] = 7
*****************
q[3] = 4
q[4] = 3
q[3] + q[4] = 7
```